# Presentation issue of similar passes in the Passbook (iOS6)

Tags: ios6, passbook

I made two sample coupon pkpass with same passTypeIdentifier and different serialNumber,after add into Passbook,they were arranged together,like photos bellow:

[left & right coupon](https://plus.google.com/photos/109557389305865116139/albums/5794918454723321793?authkey=CLLCibfsuqeKGQ)

I could swipe to select these two pass in the Passbook.Does anyone know why this happened and how to separate these two passes as single pass in the Passbook ? Thanks!!

Comment: Change either the `passTypeIdentifier` (certificate) or use two different pass types (E.g. `coupon` and `storeCard`) to have these passes display in separate stacks.

Answer (score 2):

They have the same identifier and the same style: coupon. Passes with the same passTypeIdentifier but different styles do not group in that fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens because they have the same passTypeIdentifier